# rails storing HTTP POST into variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, http-post

I am trying to build a rails app to receive a HTTP post with a huge XML payload. Goal is to parse the XML and store parts of the content into database. My first goal is to be able to store the XML contents into a variable and parse the variable line by line. From the Q&A available here, i was able to use the below code to receive the HTTP Post.

The problem is the rails app is spitting the XML content right back to the browser. I just want the rails app to receive the XML, store and return 200 ok to the browser for now. How can i get that done?

Routes

```
post '/request' => 'application#receives_data'
```

Controller

```
def receives_data
  myXMLPost = render :text => request.raw_post
end
```

When i try this following code

```
def receives_data
  myXMLPost = request.raw_post
end
```

I get this error in development.log

> `ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template application/receives_data with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :vcf, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/opt/rails/CCH/app/views"`

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 render :text => request.raw_post
```

this part says "render the text that is the raw XML post back to the browser" - so if you want it not to render the XML - then don't have this line.

if you want to just render a 200, then just render a 200.
You can do that with a [header-only render](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-head-to-build-header-only-responses)

```
head :success
```

so:

```
def receives_data
  myXMLPost = request.raw_post
  head :success
end
```

"creating the XML" is an exercise I'll leave to the reader (that's you)... it's a pretty standard part of rails, which means it will be covered by the standard tutorials on rails.... I suggest you do some research on google for rails tutorials that involve xml eg "[rails tutorials xml](https://www.google.com.au/?q=rails%20tutorials%20xml)"

Comment: I am actually just trying to store the HTTP POST as text into variable. Not trying to create XML at all.

Comment: why are you storing it into a variable if all you're then doing is rendering success? I think you haven't fully explained what you're trying to actually do?

Comment: My apologies for the confusion. From the original post "My first goal is to be able to store the XML contents into a variable and parse the variable line by line". So the logic should be store HTTP POST into variable and return 200 OK to browser

Comment: yes, but storing it into the variable doesn't do anything with it... so what do you *actually* want to do with it?

Comment: Also - if the above is what you want (for now) - then this question is done... it has an answer. If you have a new question - then ask a new question ;)

Comment: I still cannot store the HTTP POST into variable. Original question is not answered. If you dont agree, then i guess i can open another question. However the title of the question is "rails storing HTTP POST into variable"

Comment: I tried exactly that syntax and got a missing template error log in development.log. Full error is in original post

Comment: No you didn't - not according to what you described above. What you tried (described above), you tried to *render* the xml-post. None of the things you describe in your original question are like what I've got here. and yes... it will explode without a template if you don't have a template... that's because all controller actions that are called with html format expect to render a view once they're done. That's how Rails works. What do you expect instead?

Comment: Have you read this? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

I strongly recommend you do. It'll help you figure out exactly what you want to be returned by your controller action, and what rails is expecting to be in place when you do.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I have checked marked your answer and read your guides.